# Unable to print with adobe products ("Please install a printer") Works fine in word and notepad

Tags: printer, adobe-reader

We are having some issues on a design pc.

After updating windows we are unable to print from the adobe pdf reader and other adobe products (photoshop, in design, etc.)

We got the message: Please install a printer...
Printing from within word worked fine

(virtual printers also didn't work)

OS: windows 7 home premium 64-bit

Rebooting didn't help (obvious thing we had to try)
Microsoft word seems to work fine...

Reinstalling the printers has helped

Problem is now solved but I'd still like to know what caused it?

Comment: How did you solve it? What versions of Windows, Adobe software? What printers? Did the Acrobat virtual printer work?

Comment: We solved it by reinstalling the printers, Ill update the question for you